# encoding using a random cipher

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to write a program that takes a long string of letters and characters, and creates a dictionary of {original character:random character}. It should remove characters that have already been assigned a random value.
This is what I have:

```
import random
all_chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.!?'

def make_encoder(all_chars):
    all_chars=list(all_chars)
    encoder = {}
    for c in range (0,len(all_chars)):
        e = random.choice(all_chars)
        all_chars.remove(e)
        key = all_chars[c]
        encoder[key] = e
    return encoder
```

I keep getting `index out of range: 33` on line 10 `key = all_chars[c]`

Here's my whole code, with the first problem fixed:

```
import random
all_chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.!?'

def make_encoder(all_chars):
    list_chars= list(all_chars)
    all_chars= list(all_chars)
    encoder = {}
    i=0
    while len(encoder) < len(all_chars):
        e = random.choice(all_chars)
        key = all_chars[i] 
        if key not in encoder.keys():
            encoder[key] = e
            i += 1
    return encoder

def encode_message(encoder,msg):
    encoded_msg = ""
    for x in msg:
        c = encoder[x]
        encoded_msg = encoded_msg + c

def make_decoder(encoder):
    decoder = {}
    for k in encoder:
        v = encoder[k]
        decoder[v] = k
    return decoder

def decode_message(decoder,msg):
    decoded_msg = ""
    for x in msg:
        c = decoder[x]
        decoded_msg = decoded_msg + c

def main():
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 ,.!?"
    e = make_encoder(alphabet)
    d = make_decoder(e)
    print(e)
    print(d)
    phrase = input("enter a phrase")
    print(phrase)
    encoded = encode_message(e,phrase)
    print(encoded)
    decoded = decode_message(d,encoded)
    print(decoded)
```

I now get `TypeError: iteration over non-sequence of type NoneType` for the line `for x in msg:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are altering the list. Point: never alter list while iterating over it.

`for c in range (0,len(all_chars)):` this line will iterate till length of list but at same time you removing element, so list got altered, that is why you got list out of range.

try like this:

```
import random
all_chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.!?'

def make_encoder(all_chars):
    all_char = list(all_chars)
    encoder = {}
    i=0
    while len(encoder) < len(all_char):
        e = random.choice(all_char)
        key = all_char[i] 
        if key not in encoder.keys():
            encoder[key] = e
            i += 1
    return encoder
```

output:

```
>>> make_encoder(all_chars)
{'!': '3', ',': 'l', '.': 'J', '1': 'y', '0': 'l', '3': 'G', '2': ',', '5': '6', '4': 'f', '7': 'f', '6': 'C', '9': 'F', '8': 'y', '?': 'S', 'A': 'm', 'C': 'z', 'B': 'b', 'E': 'J', 'D': '0', 'G': 'S', 'F': 'v', 'I': 'v', 'H': '?', 'K': 'd', 'J': 'X', 'M': 'o', 'L': 'O', 'O': 'Q', 'N': 'P', 'Q': 'Z', 'P': '8', 'S': 'r', 'R': 'h', 'U': 'o', 'T': 'M', 'W': 'l', 'V': '.', 'Y': 'R', 'X': 'C', 'Z': 'a', 'a': 's', 'c': 'Y', 'b': 'X', 'e': 's', 'd': 'd', 'g': 'L', 'f': 'G', 'i': 'm', 'h': 'k', 'k': 'f', 'j': '1', 'm': 'J', 'l': 'L', 'o': '2', 'n': 'N', 'q': 'n', 'p': 'l', 's': 'W', 'r': '7', 'u': 'y', 't': 'S', 'w': 'J', 'v': 'E', 'y': 'r', 'x': 'C', 'z': 'i'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never modify an iterable while you are iterating over it.

Think about it: you told Python to loop from `0` to the length of the list `all_chars`, which is `66` in the beginning.  But you are constantly shrinking this length with `all_chars.remove(e)`.  So, the loop still loops `66` times, but `all_chars` only has `66` items for the first iteration.  Afterwards, it has `65`, then `64`, then `63`, etc.

Eventually, you will run into an `IndexError` when `c` equals the length of the list (which happens at `c==33`).  Note that it is not when `c` is *greater* than the length because Python indexes start at `0`:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3][3]  # There is no index 3 because 0 is the first index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> [1, 2, 3][2]  # 2 is the greatest index
3
>>>
```

---

To fix the problem, you can either:

1. Stop removing elements from `all_chars` inside the loop.  That way, its length will always be `66`.
2. Use a `while True:` loop and break when `all_chars` is empty (you run out of characters).

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying the list as you iterate over it:

```
for c in range(0,len(all_chars)):
    e = random.choice(all_chars)
    all_chars.remove(e)
```

The range item `range(0,len(all_chars))` is only generated when the `for` loop starts. That means it will always assume its length is what it started as.

After you remove a character, `all_chars.remove(e)`, now the list is one item shorter than when the `for` loop started, leading to the eventual over-run.

How about this instead:

```
while all_chars:    # While there are chars left in the list
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making two strings or at least separating the two databases.

```
import random
all_chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.!?'

def make_encoder(all_chars):
    list_chars= list(all_chars)
    all_chars= list(all_chars) #<-------------EDIT
    encoder = {}
    for c in all_chars:
        e = random.choice(list_chars)
        list_chars.remove(e)
        key = c #<---------------EDIT
        encoder[key] = e
    return encoder<--------EDIT, unindented this line.
```

That is your issue, because you were taking away from the list you were iterating though. Making two lists, although a little messy, is the best way.

Comment: this is how I originally had it set up, but then I got `TypeError: expected index value, got str` in the same line

Comment: @enterprise42 Make them both lists then

Comment: @enterprise42 Which one?

Comment: @enterprise42 I fixed the problem. I was no longer setting `c` to a number but to a string. See the second edit

Comment: `TypeError: expected index value, got str`

Comment: but if you do that, doesn't it stop iterating?

Comment: @enterprise42 Why don't you try and see?

Comment: @enterprise42 I tried it and found the mistake. I had indented a line I shouldn't have. It now works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to remove it from the initial string (it's bad practice to change a item while iterating over it)

Just check if the item isn't already in the dictonary.

```
import random

all_chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.!?'
encoder = {}

n = 0
while len(all_chars) != len(encoder):
    rand = random.choice(all_chars)
    if rand not in encoder:
        encoder[all_chars[n]] = rand
        n += 1

for k,v in sorted(encoder.iteritems()):
    print k,v
```

By the way, your encoder may work fine by doing this, but you have no way to decode it back since you are using a random factor to build the encoder. You can fix this by using random.seed('KEY').

Comment: i can't just say  `def make_decoder(encoder):
    decoder = {}
    for k in encoder:
        v = encoder[k]
        decoder[v] = k
    return decoder`

Comment: I'll post the rest of my code so you can see what i'm trying to do

Comment: That makes sense, but it doesn't seem to be very logical to make a encoder and a decoder if to crack the coder you need the encoder instructions, a decoder should work without the encoder, usually using a key/password. So you can use encode(message,key) and then decode(encoded_message,key).